# MongoDb How do I insert a collection into another collection

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a collection in mongodb and I wanted to insert this data in another collection.

It's possible ?

my collection has 1 million records and wanted to record in another collection

example:

```
 `org: [
     {
       status: 'Good',
       name: 'BanK One',
       id: '',
       namelast: 'Close'
     }`
```

Comment: Sure this is possible but you need a separate connection to the other collection.

Comment: have any example to see me

Comment: @Paulo - please show the work you've done and where you're stuck. I'm not even sure what you mean, when you say you're trying to move data from one collection to another. Is it just a query then a write? Perhaps it's something else? Please edit your question to be specific.

Comment: I have an xpto collection that contains a thousand lines and I would like to insert the xpto collection for newxpto collection. I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THIS INSERT BETWEEN COLLECTION?

Comment: @Paulo - your comment doesn't really help clarify anything. For example: is this a one-time operation, or ongoing? (if one-time, you might consider something like Data Factory). Are you copying all data or a subset? Does the destination collection already have data that you're merging? Have you written any code to read from your original collection (and have you also written code to write to the new collection)? Are you looking for a command-line tool? (mongodb has its own import/export tools). Please edit your question accordingly (details shouldn't be placed in comments either).

Comment: I would like to do it via command line. Because I have the xpto collection and I will rename it to xptoold and I will create the new collection xpto with new unique indexes. And then I wanted to feed the xpto collection with the xptoold collection. My doubt and how to give insert xpto the data from xptoold.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$unset: "_id"},
   {$merge: "another_collection"}
])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$merge` isn't a supported pipeline stage currently, with Cosmos DB's MongoDB API.